# Does a US passport holder need an eTA to fly to Canada?

Tags: canada, us-citizens, eta

I have a US passport. Do I need an eTA to fly from the US to Toronto Canada and on to Quebec City City Canada? I am going on a Holland America cruise at Quebec City.

Comment: @BritishSam Please don't answer questions in comments. You can make that an answer.

Answer (score 4):

US citizens do not need an eTA.

> **I am an American citizen. What do I need to enter Canada?**
>
> American citizens, including American-Canadian citizens, must carry
>   proper identification and meet the basic requirements to enter Canada.
>   You do not need a Canadian passport, a Canadian visa or an eTA to
>   enter Canada if you are travelling with a valid U.S. passport.

[Government of Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1116&top=16)